# Display specific amount of text with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following PHP code to display a set of ellipses directly after 220 characters have displayed on-screen from the description field in a MySQL database.

```
...echo "<td>"; echo '<a title="'.$row['title_tag']. '" href="' . $row['hyperlink'] . '">' . substr($row['description'], 0, 220) . " . . ." .  '</a>'; echo "</td>";...
```

It works, but unfortunately this can cut off in the middle of a word.  Is there a simple way in the code that I have used above to get it to cut at the next available space or end of word?

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = preg_replace("/[^ ]*$/", '', substr($string, 0, $length));
```

This will cut a string after `$length` and then cut it to the end of the last word

Comment: Thanks schnawel007 how could I implement that if I am using the following code: echo "<td>"; echo '<a title="'.$row['title_tag']. '" href="' . $row['hyperlink'] . '">' . substr($row['description'], 0, 220) . ". . ." .  '</a>'; echo "</td>";

Comment: `echo '<a title="'.$row['title_tag']. '" href="' . $row['hyperlink'] . '">' . preg_replace("/[^ ]*$/", '', substr($row['description'], 0, 220)).'</a>';`

Answer (score 1):

Save potentially a load of wasted data being pulled out of your database, change your query to :

`SELECT .... LEFT(description, 220) as description
WHERE .... etc`

Then apply the tricks in previous answers using PHP on the string to only show up to the last space.

Comment: How can I do that if I already have a query calling all fields as follows: **SELECT * FROM image_data;** Do I have to list them all individually as **SELECT img, title, left(description, 220) as description FROM image_data**.  Is that what you mean? Thanks,  Andy ;-)

Comment: yes.  Unless you really are using all the fields from the table, you should shy away from " select * "